# uwsgi http is ambiguous

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

Im trying to  run Django application on uwsgi but get the below error.

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --home /home/cuser/.virtualenvs/vq --chdir /var/www/sid/sid -w wsgi.py

uwsgi: option '--http' is ambiguous
getopt_long() error
```

When I change from -http to --socket it works but again it says --home is ambiguous

Answer (score 27):

This is most likely because you have uwsgi installed from your distributions packaged binaries, which are more minimal in their build and lack some of the plugins.

You can fix this by either `pip install uwsgi` and replace `uwsgi` with `path/to/uwsgi/binary/installed/using/pip`. You can find that using `pip show uwsgi`.

*[Please note: use `pip3` if you're using `python3`]*

Another method would be to download the respective http/python3 plugins and running the following command:

```
uwsgi --plugins http,python --http :8000 --home /home/cuser/.virtualenvs/vq --chdir /var/www/sid/sid -w wsgi.py
```

Comment: In my case (CentOS 7), I had to install `uwsgi-router-http`, and add `--plugins http,python`.

Comment: Note that it is `--plugins python3` nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take into account when using this with distro-supplied packages, is that very probably your distribution has built uWSGI in modular way (every feature is a different plugin that must be loaded).

You have to prepend --plugin python,http to the command, and --plugin python when the HTTP router is removed

Example
Appended --plugin python

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --plugin python --home /home/cuser/.virtualenvs/vq --chdir /var/www/sid/sid -w wsgi.py
```

Answer (score -3):

try:

```
uwsgi --http=:8000 --home=/home/cuser/.virtualenvs/vq --chdir=/var/www/sid/sid -w wsgi.py
```

For some versions of getopt this should work. If not, try to put your parameters in config file or update getopt library in your system and recompile uWSGI.